# Dialogflow inline editor for Cloud Functions wont accept async

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

The firebase inline editor in Dialogflow doesn't seem to accept the async keyword. It says 'async' is not defined. How can I get around this?

```
async function add(x,y){
  return x + y;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The inline function editor deploys code to Cloud Functions, which currently runs node 6.  node 6 doesn't support ECMAScript async/await.  So, you can't use async/await in the editor.  Use promises instead.

The function you're showing isn't really async anyway, since it's not dealing with promises at all.  But if for some reason you really wanted to return a promise like async functions do:

```
function add(x,y) {
  return Promise.resolve(x + y);
}
```